# Meaning of "Uniformly" in UMP test and in UMVUE

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, inference

What does the term "Uniformly" mean in UMP(Uniformly Most Powerful) test and in UMVUE(Uniformly Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator)?

So far I have learnt, it means for all $\theta$(parameter). If it is, then for which $\theta$?

Please explain this.

Comment: Uniformly in these expressions means all over the parameter space, i.e., for all $\theta$'s. The domination of the UMP test or or the UMVU estimator over the competition is uniform in that there is no value of $\theta$ for which it does not occur.

Comment: @Xi'an Can you please tell me for the UMP test- is it "for all $\theta$'s" for the Alternative hypothesis? If it is, then why?

Comment: I do not understand the question. The test $\varphi_0$ is UMP if its power is larger than the power of any other test, for all $\theta$'s. That is the definition of being UMP. So, why the "why"?

Comment: I meant for which $\theta$. That is, the parameter space of the Null hypothesis or Alternative hypothesis?

Comment: Power is defined as the probability of a right decision under the alternative.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!